# Sqlldr log shows wrong column name when facing ORA-01722

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, oracle19c

I have a simple table with three columns.

Table name DUMMY20210527

desc DUMMY20210527

```
PID        NUMBER(10) 
VDATE      DATE       
SID        NUMBER(10)
```

Control File

```
LOAD DATA CHARACTERSET JA16SJIS
APPEND INTO TABLE "DUMMY20210527" fields terminated by '\t' trailing nullcols
(
pid ,
vdate date "YYYY/MM/DD",
sid
)
```

Data File

```
a   b   c
1   2019/01/10  X
```

When trying to load this file log is showing error in column vdate. however wrong value x is provided in column sid

Log

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "DUMMY20210527", column VDATE.
ORA-01722: invalid number
Table "DUMMY20210527":
  0 Rows successfully loaded.
  1 Row not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
```

However if the following file is loaded then proper error message is shown

```
a   b   c
X   2019/01/10  1
```

Log

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "DUMMY20210527", column PID.
ORA-01722: invalid number


Table "DUMMY20210527":
  0 Rows successfully loaded.
  1 Row not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
```

Oracle version used: Oracle 19c

Comment: This looks very much like an issue reported in [Doc ID 2047931.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2047931.1); though that suggests they thought it didn't happen any more. You might need to raise a service request? Not sure this is really on-topic for SO though - not much we can do about it.

Comment: I agree with Alex RE: Oracle support document.  That issue may have been fixed for most situations but I see you are using `CHARACTERSET JA16SJIS` and maybe that characterset may still be affected.  Check out Alex' link to find workarounds.

Comment: Thank you. The work around as mentioned in the document worked i.e. changed cursor sharing from forced to exact. Still will raise a service request to Oracle regarding this issue.

Comment: Which version are you running? I'm not able to reproduce on 19.6 (which is now a pretty old release)